# How to synchronize QWidgets with menu bar?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am new to Qt creator. I have a stacked widget with 3 pages. I also have a menu bar that contains : `open \\ create`. The QWidget contains 2 pages. I would like to ask how can I synchronize Open with first page and create from menu bar with second page from stacked widget?

I did write: `ui->stackedWidget->show();` but it's printing the second page to both open and create.

Need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare two slots in your MainWindow class. For instance:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
  ...
public slots:
  void slotOpen() ;
  void slotCreate() ;
  ...
  } ;
```

Then, in your MainWindow constructor (assuming your menu actions are `actionOpen` and `actionCreate`):

```
connect (ui -> actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(slotOpen())) ;
connect (ui -> actionCreate, SIGNAL(triggered()), SLOT(slotCreate())) ;
```

The slot functions:

```
void MainWindow::slotOpen()
  {
  ui -> stackedWidget -> setCurrentIndex(0) ;
  }

void MainWindow::slotCreate()
  {
  ui -> stackedWidget -> setCurrentIndex(1) ;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can connect the menu actions to the `QStackedWidget` Slot [`setCurrentIndex`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html#currentIndex-prop). This will allow you to display the correct widget when clicking on the menu.

Comment: That won't work. In the connect() call the SLOTs can not be assigned to be called with spesific parameter values.

Comment: -1. What Xenakios said. Also it has to be `SIGNAL(triggered())`, not `SIGNAL(triggered)`. Oh, and there's a parenthesis mismatch problem too.

Comment: I wrote it without any IDE to check... I would only signal the setCurrentIndex slot exists... So I will remove the sample